# Keep precision while converting string to decimal

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, database-migration, schema.yml

I have a database with columns of string type with decimal values in them. Those decimals are longitudes and latitudes, so these numbers can be long of 8 units after the dot.

I want to convert the type from string to decimal. The problem is that when I assign decimal type in my `schema.yml`, it rounds the values to 2 units after the dot, and if I had a scale parameter of 12 and size of 16 (to be large), it rounds it to 2 units after the dot and adds 10 zeros at the end.

```
lat: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
```

to

```
lat: { type: decimal, scale: 12, size:16, notnull: false }
```

Is there a way to migrate these columns to decimal type without losing precision?

Comment: Which SGBD are you using? Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a decimal?

Because regarding an [old ticket on the Doctrine bug tracker](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-62), it seems better to use a `float` instead of a `decimal` for this kind of case.

Give it a try.